# Enable icons on buttons in 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 the command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface buttons-have-icons true
```

doesn't work anymore. No icons on buttons. How can I enable this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I was able to enable button images for a specific GTK+ 2 C++ application by adding this to the source code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkSettings * gtksettings = gtk_settings_get_default();
gtk_settings_set_long_property(gtksettings, "gtk-button-images", 1, "XProperty");
```